# How to put JAR files in the /WEB-INF/lib/ folder before exporting the program into a .war file and deploying it in TomCat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, digital-ocean

Just what the question says. I am using Eclipse. I can't copy and paste JAR files into the /lib folder that I make.

The TomCat Developer Guide says to put JAR files into this folder for the app to work:

> /WEB-INF/lib/ - This directory contains JAR files that contain Java class files (and associated resources) required for your application, such as third party class libraries or JDBC drivers.

Details:

I am using DigitalOcean to deploy an application through TomCat.

I get the Home Page up, but when I click to another link on the home page, I get this 500 error:

```
Message The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

How do I solve this please?

Comment: You should absolutely use Maven or Gradle to manage your project (and for that matter, modern projects use frameworks like Spring Boot or Micronaut that handle all of the packaging and deployment setup for you).

Comment: @chrlis how do I do that on TomCat? The application I am using is on eclipse, has maven, and is on Spring Boot (MVC pattern). But when I package it into a war file to upload to tomcat (which is what it needs to deploy), I then click to a link on the home page and it is giving me the 500 error I wrote above. What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve], e.g. show simple code and a simple pom that help reproduce the problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- how do I do that on TomCat? The application I am using is on eclipse, has maven, and is on Spring Boot (MVC pattern). But when I package it into a war file to upload to tomcat (which is what it needs to deploy), I then click to a link on the home page and it is giving me the 500 error I wrote above. What should I do?

Comment: @OlafKock That is one thing I am confused about. I haven't included a POM File. From what I understand, JARs will cover all dependencies that a POM file brings, so therefore a POM file is not needed. Am I correct on that? If so, I would be appreciative of if I could learn from you what sorts of reproducible examples I should post to make this post worthwhile, as I am still too novice to quite understand what is needed. Thank you for your time.